# FIlter and unfilter button in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to filter some data by their category id. Right now I can filter by category with value: 1. What I am trying to achieve is when the button is clicked again, it should clear the filter. Here is the code below:

```js
const onPress = () => {
    const filteredResults = results.filter((result) =>{
        return result.category === 1;
    });
    setResults(filteredResults);
};
```

The button:

```js
<Button onPress={() =>{onPress()}}>Lajme</Button>
```

How can I implement this function in the same button:

```js
const clearFilter = () => {
    const filteredResults = results
    setResults(filteredResults);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the current filter (`category`) with `useState()`, and whenever you update it (see `toggleFilter`) check if the current filter is already set. If it is, reset (change to `null` for example).

```js
const { useState, useMemo } = React;

const Demo = ({ results }) => {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(null);
  
  const filteredResults = useMemo(() => results.filter(result => category === null || result.category === category), [results, category]);
  
  const toggleFilter = cat => setCategory(c => cat === c ? null : cat);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => toggleFilter(1)}>Cat 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => toggleFilter(2)}>Cat 2</button>
      
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(filteredResults)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const results = [{ category: 1 }, { category: 2 }, { category: 2 }, { category: 1 }]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo results={results} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i need it for react native. I will update the tags sorry.

Comment: React native also have `useState` and `useMemo`. Just replace the JSX to whatever you are using for the view.

Comment: I tried it but couldn't implement it successfully. My results data comes from an api and i have it in a flatlist component that I declare in home screen like this `<ResultList results={results} navigation={navigation} />`. now should i replace results with filteredResults const there ?

Comment: Did just that and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use a state variable to know if the filter is currently applied or not.

```js
const [isFiltered, setFiltered] = useState(false);

const onPress = () => {
    if (isFiltered) {
        setResults(results); // Update results without filter
        setFiltered(false); // Update the state
    } else {
        const filteredResults = results.filter(({ category }) => category === 1); // Filter the results
        setResults(filteredResults); // Update results
        setFiltered(true); // Update the state
    }
};

// ...

<Button onPress={onPress}>Lajme</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it but didnt work unfortunately. Im filtering some api results and they are rendered in a flat list  `<ResultList results={results} navigation={navigation} />` this is the list that comes in homepage